# Initial position of a SystemWindow (Cuis Smalltalk)

Tags: smalltalk, morphic

I have made a subclass #Mosaic1 of **#SystemWindow** and I would like to control the initial position of the window. How do I do that? Class **#RealEstateAgent** is involved but how? The class comment says

```
Responsible for real-estate management on the screen, 
which is to say, controlling where new windows appear, 
with what sizes, etc.  5/20/96 sw
```

So I am asking for an explanation how to configure and use the class #RealEstateAgent.

Notes:

- **#RealEstateAgent** is a singleton. It only has class side methods
- It is only referenced by **#SystemWindow**
- A new SystemWindow gets its initial extent from  *RealEstateAgent class>> standardWindowExtent*

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to bypass the class #RealEstateAgent and write your own code to handle the initial size and position of a new instance of SystemWindow.

This may be done by overriding SystemWindow>>openInWorld:extent:

```
openInWorld: aWorld extent: extent
"This msg and its callees result in the window being activeOnlyOnTop"
aWorld addMorph: self.

self morphPosition: 
        (RealEstateAgent initialFrameFor: self world: aWorld) topLeft;
         morphExtent: extent.

aWorld startSteppingSubmorphsOf: self.


"Do it deferred. Was needed for text cursor to start blinking 
    if (Preferences disable: #focusFollowsMouse) "

WorldState addDeferredUIMessage: [ self activate ]
```

Replace

```
self morphPosition: 
        (RealEstateAgent initialFrameFor: self world: aWorld) topLeft;
         morphExtent: extent.
```

Calculate

- thePositionOfTheWindow
- theExtentOfTheWindow

Then do

```
self morphPosition: thePositionOfTheWindow  morphExtent: theExtentOfTheWindow.
```